# Creating a Linq group by query

Tags: c#, linq

```
            //SELECT table1.GG_ITEM, Sum(table1.REM_QTY) AS SumPerGG_ITEM
            //FROM table1
            //WHERE (table1.SUGG_DOCK_DATE Is Not Null)
            //GROUP BY table1.GG_ITEM
            //ORDER BY table1.GG_ITEM;

            var try1 = (from row in db2.Dumps select new { Type1 = row.GA_ITEM, Type2 = row.REM_QTY });

            Debug.Print(":::::try1:::::");
            foreach (var row in try1)
            {
                Debug.Print(row.Type1.ToString());
                Debug.Print(row.Type2.ToString());
            }

            var try2 = (from row in db2.Dumps group row by row.GA_ITEM into g select new { Type1 = g.Key, Type2 = g.ToList() });

            Debug.Print("::::try2:::::");
            foreach (var row in try2)
            {
                Debug.Print(row.Type1.ToString());
                Debug.Print(row.Type2.ToString());
            }
```

I'm converting an Access SQL query to Linq. The two columns I am selecting from my table Dumps are `GA_ITEM` and `REM_QTY`. My `try1` is working out just fine and I see the contents of both columns printed out. My `try1` is not yet duplicating the functionality of the Access SQL query.

My `try2` is an attempt at grouping. For my `try2` `row.Type1.ToString()` is readable however `row.Type2.ToString()` is showing up in the output window as:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[garminaspsandbox3.Models.Dump]
```

What I really would like to do is in try2 select `GA_ITEM` and `REM_QTY` like I did in try1 and group by GA_ITEM however those fields aren't showing up in my autocomplete for the g object.

Does anyone know how to do this in Linq?

Thank you for posting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Type2` property holds a `List`, not a *single* item,So you need to use another loop and iterate over the items in that group:

```
foreach (var row in try2)
{
    Debug.Print(row.Type1.ToString());
    foreach(var item in row.Type2)
    {
        Debug.Print(item.GA_ITEM);
        Debug.Print(item.REM_QTY);
    }
}
```